# Does ng-hide hide the contained DOM elements?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following snippet:

```
                <p>AAA</p>
                <div ng-show="files.length == 0">
                <p>BBB</p>
                    <tr class="no-files">
                <p>CCC</p>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p class="no-files">There are no files to load.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
```

It seems like the `ng-show` is only marking its own `div` as (in)visible, and not also *the contents of that div*.  In my application, the "there are no files..." message is displayed regardless of the number of elements in `files`.  I expected entire div to be shown/hidden. Have I done something wrong or is this how `ng-show` works?

In the example above, when the number of files is greater than zero, AAA and CCC are displayed.

Is this the proper behavior or have I done something wrong?

Comment: that whole block should be invisible. Something is definitely wrong

Comment: It might have something to do with that paragraph block you just added inside your tablerow. I don't think you can place that element there.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. `p` and `div` in a `table` should be contained within a `td` or `th`.

Comment: I wonder if it is because I'm plopping a DIV in weird places in a table.

Comment: @Blazemonger this is a snippet.  The `table` is there.

Comment: paste in the whole table. I think your table is messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd say you have invalid HTML.  `<div>`s can't contain table rows.  Try removing the wrapper `<div>` and putting `ng-show` on the `<tr>`.

Comment: yep, I had determined that the `DIV`s were the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`p` can't appear in a `table` outside of a table cell. Neither can `div`. Use `ng-show` on the `tr` element(s) instead.

```
<tr class="no-files" ng-show="files.length == 0">
      <td colspan="2">
           <p class="no-files">There are no files to load.</p>
      </td>
</tr>
```